# Override Doctrine2 types in Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, types, doctrine-orm

I would like to use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) objects in my Symfony 3.2 application instead of the SPL \DateTime object. I found a set of DoctrineExtension classes in [here](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions).

Edited my config.yml file:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        ...
        types:
            carbondatetime: DoctrineExtensions\Types\CarbonDateTimeType
            carbondate: DoctrineExtensions\Types\CarbonDateType
            carbontime: DoctrineExtensions\Types\CarbonTimeType
        mapping_types:
            datetime: carbondatetime
            date: carbondate
            enum: string
            time: carbontime
```

I successfully check if the types are loaded with:

```
Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap()
```

And the mapping as well is working properly (returns `carbondatetime`):

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
     ->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()
     ->getDoctrineTypeMapping('datetime');
```

I execute a query over a Doctrine repository and still get DateTime objects. It is working in 2 cases:

- Changing the Entity to `@ORM\Column(type="carbondatetime")`
- Or executing the following code `\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::overrideType('datetime', 'DoctrineExtensions\Types\CarbonDateTimeType');`

Is there a Best-Practice to **override** the Doctrine DBAL types? Preferably in the YAML configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Woah.... Like always, as soon you ask the question you find the solution:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        ...
        types:
            datetime: DoctrineExtensions\Types\CarbonDateTimeType
            date: DoctrineExtensions\Types\CarbonDateType
            time: DoctrineExtensions\Types\CarbonTimeType
        mapping_types:
            enum: string
```